# Increasing the resolution of a 24 bit ADC over a small voltage range

Tags: adc

I am using the Cirrus Logic 24 bit ADC CS5532 in bipolar mode over the range -2V5 to +2V5 to take position measurements for a PID control system. The system is in equilibrium and fully controlled when the input is zero volts - that is the PID target.

The PID input swings +/-2.5V

So, I am mainly interested in getting high precision conversions about that 0V point.

One strategy would be to pre-amplify the input signal about the zero and clip it to the input limits of the ADC. However, the chip has a programmable amplifier on board, so perhaps I could set the amplification factor to (say) x4 and have it clip internally. That means I get 2 more bits of resolution around the point that is of interest.

Does this sound plausible?

Comment: By what factor are you oversampling the signal? Presumably you cannot be bang-on the Nyquist rate, right?

Comment: @andy Sampling is 100Hz, which is considerably faster than the response of the system. Overall though, I only seem to be getting 19 bits of resolution at best, and I need at least 3 more

Comment: Adding four consecutive samples gets 1 bit more resolution.

Comment: @andy Yes, but there are various tradeoffs involved and the ADC already does filtering. I can add some more later, but I need it as good as possible before I start doing the statistical cheating and fancy filtering

Comment: Yes, your suggestion sounds plausible. I was just offering up an alternative. Another alternative to get one more bit is to half the reference voltages.

Comment: 'Only getting 19 bits'? How are you defining that? Is your noise at that level, or are the values jumping 32 LSBs at a time? There's no reason you shouldn't amplify all the way down so that only +/- 1 mV about 0 is full scale on your ADC, if you can cope with the saturation outside that region. You might want to use anti-parallel diodes in a clipper arrangement so you can have huge gain for the +/- 500 mV region, then the diodes reduce the signal swing beyond that, so you still get monotonic response but reduced gain outside it.

Comment: I think you are confused between resolution and accuracy. A 24-bit ADC gives you 24 bits of resolution **by definition**. If you are actually talking about the error in the measurement then you are talking about **accuracy**. Accuracy is not improved by oversampling, and it might not be improved by amplifying the signal...everything depends on where the errors are introduced into your system.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson 24 bits of resolution spread across 5V is not going to be as good as 24 bits spread over 0.5V

Comment: This sounds completely plausible.

Comment: @DirkBruere It depends on what you mean by "as good as". The resolution will be better but the precision and accuracy might even be worse. It depends entirely on where the errors are being introduced into your system. Amplifying the signal by a factor of 4 won't help if there is a voltage offset in the amplifier, for example.